# calculate high power of Matrix

Tags: matrices, exponentiation, diagonalization

---

how can I calculate $\pmatrix {1&0.5\\0&-0.5}^{2017}$ ?

For example, what are the methods to  calculate the high power of the matrix

Comment: What do you mean : **role to calculate ...** ?

Comment: what are the methods to calculate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A$ be your matrix. It has two eigenvectors, $(1,0)$, and $(-1,3)$, whose eigenvalues are $1$ and $-\frac12$ respectively. So, let$$T=\begin{pmatrix}1&-1\\0&3\end{pmatrix}.$$Then$$T^{-1}.A.T=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&-\frac12\end{pmatrix}.$$Therefore,$$T^{-1}.A^n.T=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&\left(-\frac12\right)^n\end{pmatrix},$$and so$$A^n=T.\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&\left(-\frac12\right)^n\end{pmatrix}.T^{-1}.$$

Comment: I reach to this answer [1 0.33, 0, .00033] using this method: A^2017=q1A+q2 I   and (eigval)^2017=q1A+q2 I     I got to 1^2017=q1+q2 and -.5^2017=0=q1+q2